# What are wrong in these sentences and why?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

1. He takes the total of money in the Piggy Bank.
2. He takes the total of money into the Piggy Bank.
3. He takes the total of money into Piggy Bank.

Comment: And what are your thoughts on the topic?

Comment: What do you mean by **take**?

Comment: @npst i thought the first, but the money is inside, all them can be ok or all them can be wrong, i don't know

Comment: @Lambie I'm develop a program, I use 'getMoney' to know if the Piggy Bank has a quantity of money, only to get some information,  but I need another verb as 'take' to refer to the action of reduce the amount of money available, in this sense of a person gets these quantity

Answer (score 1):

To take money out of a bank; He took 1,000 pounds out of his bank account.

- **He took out all the money in the Piggy Bank**.
- **He took all the money out of the Piggy Bank**
- **He took the total amount out of the  Piggy Bank**.

Idiom: to take money out of an account or bank or to take out money from an account.